# On Windows 8.1, in Emacs Ghostscript doesn't work, while on commandline it does

Tags: error-handling, path, customization

### Edited question of August 2017:

After a long search I found the reason, why a wonderful software called pdfsizeopt (for my question from April 2017 see below) does not work, when called from Emacs, while it works when called from command line:

While working with Emacs, since some time I switched to UNC pathes to my files! Something like `//SERVER/path/to/file/filename.*`. *But* the network share, where all the files reside in thousands of folders, is mapped ("R:"). I didn't use that, because UNC worked.

When I opended cmd.exe somewhere, Windows always took the mapped path and not the UNC path. I did not notice this until yesterday.

When I started pdfsizeopt from Emacs, there was no swap of the UNC path for a mapped path.

To run pdfsizeopt from within Emacs, I only added these lines into my .emacs:

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
'(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
'("pdfsizeopt" "pdfsizeopt.exe %s.pdf %s.pdf" TeX-run-command t t :help "Run 
pdfsizeopt.exe") t))
```

Obviously Emacs prepends the full UNC path to the file name, e.g.:
    //SERVER/path/to/file/filename.pdf

New Questions:

1. But why on earth does this mechanism lead to the failure finding Ghostscript, wherever it is installed, be it in `C:\Program Files\`, be it in the folder of pdfsizeopt, regardless whether Ghostscript is in the $PATH ?
2. Is this an Emacs bug?

### Question from April 2017

I'm using Emacs / AUCTeX (OS: Win 8.1) to compile LaTeX files. To shrink the PDF afterwards, I'm using [pdfsizeopt](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt). The command is easy:

```
pdfsizeopt.exe input.pdf output.pdf
```

OK, opening cmd.exe in a folder of a PDF, which I'd like to shrink, it works. This is the relevant part of the output (many lines cut out, irrelevant):

```
T:\somefolder>pdfsizeopt.exe name-of-pdf.pdf name-of-pdf.pdf
info: This is pdfsizeopt ZIP rUNKNOWN size=105563.
info: loading PDF from: name-of-pdf.pdf
info: loaded PDF of 858466 bytes
info: found 92 obj offsets and 1 obj streams in xref stream
info: separated to 90 objs + xref + trailer
warning: cannot parse obj 24: pdfsizeopt.main.PdfIndirectLengthError: missing ob
j for indirect /Length 45 0 R at ofs=20434
info: found 6 Type1 fonts loaded
info: writing Type1CConverter (435161 font bytes) to: psotmp.5420.conv.tmp.ps
info: using Ghostscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin32c.exe": GPL
 Ghostscript 9.21 (2017-03-16)
info: executing Type1CConverter with Ghostscript: "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9
.21\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prin
ter -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged -sOutputFile=psotmp.5420.conv
.tmp.pdf -f psotmp.5420.conv.tmp.ps
Type1CConverter: using interpreter GPL Ghostscript 921 20170316
Type1CConverter: converting font /TBQTVH+LinBiolinum to /Obj0000000077
Type1CConverter: converting font /MKHCTZ+LMMathSymbols8-Regular to /Obj000000008
7
Type1CConverter: all OK
info: loading PDF from: psotmp.5420.conv.tmp.pdf
info: loaded PDF of 31339 bytes
info: separated to 30 objs + xref + trailer
info: found 6 fonts in GS output
info: optimized total Type1 font size 435229 to Type1C font size 22200 (5%)
info: optimized Type1 font XObject 87,86: new size=658 (25%)
info: found 6 Type1C fonts loaded
info: writing Type1CParser (22080 font bytes) to: psotmp.5420.conv.parse.tmp.ps
info: executing Type1CParser with Ghostscript: "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.21
\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=nullpage -sDataFile=psotmp.5420
.conv.parsedata.tmp.ps -f psotmp.5420.conv.parse.tmp.ps
Type1CParser: using interpreter GPL Ghostscript 921 20170316
Type1CParser: all OK
info: parsed 6 Type1C fonts
info: eliminated 1 duplicate objs
info: eliminated 21 unused objs in 21 classes
warning: obj 24 missing, referenced by objs [21]...
info: compressed 2 streams, kept 2 of them uncompressed
info: saving PDF with 47 objs to: name-of-pdf.pdf
info: generated object stream of 3118 bytes in 37 objects (18%)
info: generated 40874 bytes (5%)


T:\somefolder>
```

As you can observe, Ghostscript is being found by pdfsizeopt. All is well.

Now, if I'm calling it via Emacs (64-bit):

```
Running `pdfsizeopt' on `name-of-pdf' with ``pdfsizeopt.exe "name-of-pdf".pdf "name-of-pdf".pdf''
info: This is pdfsizeopt ZIP rUNKNOWN size=105563.
info: loading PDF from: name-of-pdf.pdf
info: loaded PDF of 858466 bytes
info: found 92 obj offsets and 1 obj streams in xref stream
info: separated to 90 objs + xref + trailer
warning: cannot parse obj 24: pdfsizeopt.main.PdfIndirectLengthError: missing obj for indirect /Length 45 0 R at ofs=20434

info: found 6 Type1 fonts loaded
info: writing Type1CConverter (435161 font bytes) to: psotmp.6548.conv.tmp.ps
info: this Ghostscript does not work: "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin32c.exe"
info: this Ghostscript does not work: "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin32c.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt_win32exec\python26.zip\runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt_win32exec\python26.zip\runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt.single\__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt.single\mainrun.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt.single\pdfsizeopt\main.py", line 8240, in main
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt.single\pdfsizeopt\main.py", line 5341, in ConvertType1FontsToType1C
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt.single\pdfsizeopt\main.py", line 5058, in GenerateType1CFontsFromType1
  File "C:\pdfsizeopt\pdfsizeopt.single\pdfsizeopt\main.py", line 140, in GetGsCommand
AssertionError: Could not find a working Ghostscript.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Apr 25 17:20:00
```

**Why on earth does the same Ghostscript installation not work, if called from Emacs?**

Is there an issue with the spaces in "Program Files (x86)"?

In my .emacs, I have defined calling pdfsizeopt this way:

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
'(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
'("pdfsizeopt" "pdfsizeopt.exe %s.pdf %s.pdf" TeX-run-command t t :help "Run pdfsizeopt.exe") t))
```

Has been working for years.

Comment: You can check the value of your environmental PATH variable within Emacs by evaluating `(getenv "PATH")`.  E.g., `M-x eval-expression RET (getenv "PATH") RET`.  Check that and see if your Ghostscript application path is somewhere on one of those elements.  If not, then you'll need to adjust the path either in Windows or in Emacs.  Alternatively, you can use an absolute path to Ghostscript and set the applicable variable based on whatever Elisp library you are using that needs to find it.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you, but Ghostscript /bin as well as /lib are in the "PATH" of Windows. Otherwise pdfsizeopt would not have found it when run from commandline.